# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC unexpected results

Tags: php, database

I am having a problem with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC option when fetching results from database. I am getting array that has numbers as indexes instead of row names. Why is this happening?

```
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(15) "example1" [2]=> NULL } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(10) "example2" [2]=> int(1) } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> string(17) "example3" [2]=> int(1) } [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> string(3) "example4" [2]=> int(1) } [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> string(9) "example5" [2]=> NULL } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) is not a method of PDO, but of MySQLi.

You might want to use :

```
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. It works.